# Burnination of [dashboard]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

> A dashboard is a user interface that organizes and presents information in a way that is easy to read to the user of a website. A dashboard typically indicates items which require urgent actions at the top of the page, moving into less important statistics at the bottom.

What is the actual productive use of [dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dashboard) tag? It is so subjective of what would be considered a dashboard, and across languages and interfaces can mean many different things. I can't imagine a useful scenario for this tag other than trying to relate you need some sort of interface code help which you could specify in any question.

Comment: I will add it to my dashboard.

Comment: Something based on Braiam's comment isn't bad, but how about "Burnination by the [dashboard] light"?

Comment: How much love does a burnination request need before it gets nixed?

Comment: It may help your cause to go through the [criteria for burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) and address the four criteria in your post.